# wp query shortcode wordpress with categories number of posts and pagination

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to make a shortcode of a query for a website that sells tickets for the theatre, I want to be able to turn on and off pagination choose the category and the number of posts per page in the shorcode. I cant get the pagination at all either. I am new to shortcodes so I dont know what I am doing wrong.

This is what I tried.

```
function test_posts(  ) {
    ob_start();



// WP_Query arguments


$paged = (get_query_var(‘paged’)) ? get_query_var(‘paged’) : 1;
$args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'teatro',
    'posts_per_page'         => '4',
    'paged' => $paged
);

shortcode_atts(
    $args  
);






// The Query
$featured_post_query = new WP_Query( $args['category_name'] );

// The Loop
if ( $featured_post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $featured_post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $featured_post_query->the_post();

        ?>
                        <div class="teatro-all">

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(gallery); ?>

                            <h2 class="teatro-group teatro-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <h5 class="teatro-group teatro-fecha"> <?php the_field('fecha'); ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="teatro-group teatro-precio" ><?php the_field('precio'); ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="teatro-group teatro-lugar" ><?php the_field('lugar'); ?> </h5>

                            <center><a class="teatro-buy teatro-button" href="<?php the_field('comprar'); ?> ">COMPRAR</a><br></center>

                            <center><a class="teatro-read-more teatro-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">LEER MAS</a></center> 



                        </div>
                        <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
                         pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
      } ?>  
                        <?php

    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}



// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}

function test_shortcode() {

$output = test_posts();

$output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the _expected_ result of that?  What is the _actual_ result?  What have you tried to fix whatever's wrong?

Comment: I am trying to make a shortcode like this [test category_name="teatro" posts_per_page="4" ] I want to be able to change this things throughj the short code everything works  I just cant make it into a shortcode..

Comment: You should read the docs for [add_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).  There are examples that show how the arguments are passed to, and referenced in, the callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress creating shortcode with custom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784363/wordpress-creating-shortcode-with-custom-value)

Answer (score 0):

To create a shortcode, you can consult it directly in the wordpress codex: [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Now if you want to pass parameters to a shortcode the syntax is the following: `[your_shortcode category="example_category" posts_per_page="2"]` and you must make the following code:

```
// [your_shortcode category="example_category" posts_per_page= "6"]
function prefix_your_shortcode( $atts ) 
{
    $default_atts = ['category' => 'teatro', 'posts_per_page' => 4];
    shortcode_atts($default_atts , $atts);

    //Do your logic and consult with WP QUERY here
}
add_shortcode( 'your_shortcode', 'prefix_your_shortcode');
```

Now explaining a bit and correcting the code that you exposed, when you want to pass parameters through a shortcode, the function you call, you must pass a parameter "$ atts" that would be the parameters passed by the shortcode (category and posts_per_page) . Then "shortcode_atts" causes you to put default attributes in case you do not place any (in this case it is theater and 4). I hope that with this I can help you.